A walking cane here at my side
I have a question about the song Englishman in New York. Why "is" missed in the phrase "a walking cane here at my side"?

It's not a "complete sentence" but a noun-phrase.  "See me walking down Fifth Avenue / A walking cane here at my side"  Compare: "Look at the circus seal, a beach ball on its nose".   The locative prepositional phrase is understood to supply information about the noun without an explicit predicate.

Please give more context than just one phrase, although I ought to be ashamed not to know 1987 Sting by heart. Meanwhile @TimR that's an answer (arguably, if any word is deleted, it's "with")

As @TimR says, "a walking cane here at my side" and "a beach ball on its nose" are basically  noun phrases, but they're being used adverbially (having "deleted" a preposition such as with).

If I remember correctly how BillJ would characterize these NPs, I think he'd say the NPs are  ascriptive.

A reasonable explanation would probably be that if the line had 'with' in that place, it wouldn't fit the tune.

@AndyBonner - I knew a bloke who kept being turned down for jobs because he always answered 'yes' at interviews when asked if he had a police record. It was only 'Walking on the Moon', he complained to me.

@MichaelHarvey as a lad I went for a summer job in a department store. The manager asked "How are you with cash?" and I replied "I have a few pounds, thank you" but I got the job.
